# Изменение названия кнопки в зависимости от состояния - скрытие/показ c запоминанием состояния

Tags: javascript, html

Предложите свой код или помогите доделать данный, который выполняет показ и скрытие с запоминанием состояния. Единственное чего мне не хватает - это того, чтобы название кнопки менялось на "скрыть" и "показать" в зависимости от текущего состояния.

```
<div id="myShowBlock">
Lorem ipsum
</div>
    <a href="javascript:toggleBlock()">Подробнее</a>
    <script>
    (function() {
        var toggle = function(element, show) {
            element.style.display = show ? 'block' : 'none';
        };
        var block = document.getElementById('myShowBlock');
        var visible = localStorage.hasOwnProperty('visible') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('visible')) : true;
        toggle(block, visible);
        window.toggleBlock = function() {
            toggle(block, visible = !visible);
            localStorage.setItem('visible', visible);
        };
    })();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такой вариант:
Заменить `<a href="javascript:toggleBlock()">Подробнее</a>` на

```
<a href="javascript:toggleBlock()" id="myShowBlockBtn">Подробнее</a>
```

После `toggle(block, visible = !visible);` добавить

```
document.getElementById('myShowBlockBtn').innerHTML = (visible?'скрыть':'показать');
```

Кажется, это делает то, что Вам нужно

Answer (score 1):

здесь не работает, не знаю почему, но попробуйте на месте

```js
 (function() {
   var c = document.querySelector("#myShowBlock"),
     b = document.querySelector(".show"),
     a = +localStorage.getItem("visible");
   b.addEventListener("click", function() {
     c.classList.toggle("hide");
     a = +c.classList.contains("hide");
     localStorage.setItem("visible", a);
     b.textContent = ["Скрыть", "Показать"][a]
   });
   !a && b.click()
 })();
```

```css
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div id="myShowBlock" class="hide">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
<a href="#" class="show">Показать</a>
```